# function only works on first child of each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code for disabling/enabling a submit button:

```js
var orderText = $('#order input[type="text"]');
var orderCheck = $('#order :checkbox');
var orderSelect = $('#order select').not('#sel_option_img');

var enableOrDisableSubmit = function() {

  var textEntered = orderText.val().length > 0;
  var orderChecked = orderCheck.not('.others').is(':checked');
  var orderSelected = $(orderSelect).val() != '';

  if (textEntered || orderChecked || orderSelected)
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

};
orderText.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
orderCheck.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
orderSelect.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="order">
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select class="second">
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

The code only works for the first child of each element (input and select elements), but not on the second, third, fourth, etc, except for the checkboxes which are working properly.

Any hint to write the code in a correct way?

Comment: Well, `orderText.val()` will return the value of the first selected element, just as the documentation says.

Comment: That's by design When you perform `orderText.val()`  it will return value of first element. Use `.each()`

Comment: I mean the code works only on the first "input type text" element and on the first select box, no matter which option is select. So, how to change the code due to make it work an ALL select boxes and ALL "input type text" boxes?

Comment: You probably want to use `$(this).val()` inside the event handler. Learn more about event handling basics: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: On a side note, there's no need for the extra `$()` around the `orderSelect` in the function. `orderSelect` is already a jQuery object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this on fiddle it works fine me on fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/7P3ab. I have changed two line in your code:

```
var orderText = $('#order input[type="text"]');
var orderCheck = $('#order :checkbox');
var orderSelect = $('#order select').not('#sel_option_img');

var enableOrDisableSubmit = function() {
    var textEntered = $(orderText).filter(function(){
       return $(this).val() != '';}).length > 0;  // here filter method is added for textboxes
    var orderChecked = orderCheck.not('.others').is(':checked');
    var orderSelected = $(orderSelect).filter(function(){
       return $(this).val() != '';}).length > 0;   // here filter method is added for select

    if (textEntered || orderChecked || orderSelected)
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    else
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

};
orderText.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
orderCheck.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
orderSelect.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
```

Full snippet:

```js
var orderText = $('#order input[type="text"]');
var orderCheck = $('#order :checkbox');
var orderSelect = $('#order select').not('#sel_option_img');

var enableOrDisableSubmit = function() {
  var textEntered = $(orderText).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != '';
  }).length > 0; // here filter method is added for textboxes
  var orderChecked = orderCheck.not('.others').is(':checked');
  var orderSelected = $(orderSelect).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != '';
  }).length > 0; // here filter method is added for select

  if (textEntered || orderChecked || orderSelected)
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

};
orderText.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
orderCheck.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
orderSelect.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="order">
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select class="second">
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: It' works, but once the button is enabled it does not disable again. Why?

Comment: I have got the reason, need changes in place of orderedSelected.

Comment: I have edited my answer now it should work as expected.

Comment: This is working fine on jsfiddle for me. I have just pasted this code in the fiddle you gave in the question.

Comment: Aha...so i think the issue must be somewhere else in the rest of the code.

Comment: I you think this is the answer of you what you asked, please accept this as the answer of this question, Thanks.

Comment: I've fount the problem! Great help! Thanks again and good evening.

Comment: I think `.filter(f).length > 0` is harder to read and less efficient as `.is(f)`.

Comment: @Robert Didn't think about it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function that returns a single result, then it is likely that jQuery's  [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) will be your friend.

e.g.

```
var textEntered = true;
orderText.each( function(){
  if ( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
    textEntered = false;
    // maybe also highlight the field here
    $(this).css( 'background-color', '#fcc' );
  }
});
if (!textEntered) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```js
var orderText = $('#order input[type="text"]');
var orderCheck = $('#order :checkbox');
var orderSelect = $('#order select').not('#sel_option_img');

var submit = function() {
  var notEmpty = $("#order input[type!='submit'], #order select").filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(':checkbox') ? $(this).is(':checked') : $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
  }).length == 0;
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', notEmpty);
};
orderText.change(submit);
orderCheck.change(submit);
orderSelect.change(submit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="order">
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select>
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <select class="second">
    <option value="">--please select--</option>
    <option value="12">option1</option>
    <option value="13">option2</option>
  </select> <br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="text" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
  <input type="checkbox" value="somevalue"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled>
</form>
```